# JAX-WS WebService Client - Streaming large attachements - different behavior, depending on JRE version

Tags: java, jax-ws, webservices-client

I created a WebService client from a provided WSDL-File, using the already in the JRE bundled JAX-WS API.
I generated the proxy classes with the **wsimport** tool of JDK6 Update 37.

The client should be able to download large files/data, using MTOM and streaming.

I followed the instructions provided in the [Metro user guide](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html#large-attachments).

The proxy method I'm calling returns a `DateHandler` object.

```java
package de.christopherhuebner.webservicetest.client;                                                   

import java.io.FileOutputStream;                                                                       
import java.io.OutputStream;                                                                           
import java.net.URL;                                                                                   

import javax.activation.DataHandler;                                                                   
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;                                                                      

import de.christopherhuebner.webservicetest.ImageServer;                                               
import de.christopherhuebner.webservicetest.ImageServerService;                                        

public class ImageServiceClient {                                                                      

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                                          
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ImageWebService?wsdl");                               
        QName qname = new QName("http://webservicetest.christopherhuebner.de/", "ImageServerService"); 
        ImageServerService is = new ImageServerService(url, qname);                                    
        MTOMFeature mtom = new MTOMFeature();
        StreamingAttachmentFeature stf = new StreamingAttachmentFeature(null, true, 4000000L);
        ImageServer port = is.getImageServerPort(mtom, stf);                                                  
        DataHandler dh = port.getImage();                                                              
        System.out.println("Java-Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));                     
        System.out.println("DataHandler: " + dh.getClass());                                           
        System.out.println("DataSource: " + dh.getDataSource().getClass());                            
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.jpg");                                           
        dh.writeTo(out);                                                                               
        out.close();                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                  
}
```

When running this code with JRE6, the following output is printed to the console:

```
Java-Version: 1.6.0_37
DataHandler: class javax.activation.DataHandler
DataSource: class com.sun.istack.internal.ByteArrayDataSource
```

Unfortunately there is no streaming possible, as the `ByteArrayDataSource` is filled in the clients memory which causes an `OutOfMemoryException` when receiving data larger than the max heap size. When I dare to cast this `DataHandler` to a `StreamingDataHandler` as suggested in the already mentioned [user guide](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html#large-attachments), a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

When running the client with JRE7, everything is fine, as described in the [user guide](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html#large-attachments):

```
Java-Version: 1.7.0_10
DataHandler: class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.MIMEPartStreamingDataHandler
DataSource: class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.MIMEPartStreamingDataHandler$StreamingDataSource
```

Is there any possibility to get a `StreamingDataHandler` back, when using **JRE6**? 
Or am I really forced to use a newer **JAX-WS RI** version (Metro, which seems to be included in the JRE) via the `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=path_to_newer_jaxws_libs` mechanism?

When are the temp files, which are generated during streaming (*MIMExxxxx.tmp*, see `StreamingAttachmentFeature` for configuration), deleted?